# CSS Background image opacity affecting the children within it

Tags: html, image, css, opacity

I have tried changing the image opacity in css. But that is affecting all the children inside it. I have looked upon many stackoverflow questions and answers, but still it's not working for me. Hence, decided to ask a question myself.

My sample code :

```
<div id="home" class="home">

<h2 style="margin-top:130px; text-shadow: #fff 0 0 10px;  color:white; font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;">Find the suitable tutor you are looking for..</h2><br />

</div>
```

CSS :

```
#home {
  background: url(../images/home1.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
```

At first, I tried changing the opacity of the `div home`, but since it was eating up the text as well, so I decided to change the image opacity manually using GIMP.

I changed it. Even then the text doesn't look to be having the actual color. So I tried making it glow by doing some `text-shadow` and stuff. Still I don't seem to get the actual text color.

[Original Image](http://i58.tinypic.com/2zin7f7.png)

This is the actual picture without changing the opacity.

[Image with changed opacity in GIMP](http://i58.tinypic.com/2q1hp8i.png)

This is the image after changing it's opacity in GIMP.

I want the image to have this kind of opacity but the text color of the first image.

Hope I am clear. I uploaded those images here, but since I don't have reputation enough so had to share the links after uploading in another website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it somehow. What I did is I added another `div overlay_home`
and changed it's rgba in css. That makes the image only change it's opacity without the text.

```
<div id="home" class="home">

<div id="overlay_home"></div>

<h2 style="margin-top:130px; text-shadow: #fff 0 0 10px;  color:white; font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;">Find the suitable tutor you are looking for..</h2><br />

</div>

#home {
  background: url(../images/home1.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}

#overlay_home{

height:100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)


}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use pseudo element for adding `background` and add `opacity` to it

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#home {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#home:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/any) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size:100% auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="home">

  <h2 style="margin-top:130px; text-shadow: #222 0 0 10px;  color:white; font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;">Find the suitable tutor you are looking for..</h2>

  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: the text still looks blur and the image size isn't the fullpage anymore.

Comment: check the edit ? changed the text shadow color to `#222`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of (so far) is to use rgba() as your background-color; this doesn't affect its children (divs or elements).

Example:

`rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`

Comment: i have a background image.. how to rgba an image?

Answer (score 0):

Use a **div inside a div to serve the background**, and make that div only have opacity:

Use background-size:cover; to let the image cover fully. It will abide to the sie of the div.background. So you need to set the div.background to width and height 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/0mgrt069/13/

```
<div id="home" class="home">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <h2>Find the suitable tutor you are looking for..</h2>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
 h2 {
    margin-top:130px; 
    text-shadow: #fff 0 0 10px;  
    color:black; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    }
.background{
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/);
    background-size:cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]